# snowsql to be shared by all users

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I have installed snowsql using root account in linux which installed the components on /opt/snowsql directory and all of its other components in ~/.snowsql. The problem is I can run the snowsql commands using root user, but the other users cannot run the snowsql command.
How to enable this ?

Thanks,
Naveed

Comment: do bash profile needs to be created for every individual user.. ?

Comment: You need to have execute rights for **/usr/bin/snowsql** and **/usr/lib64/snowflake**. That can be done using `chmod a+x <path>`

Comment: the permissions have been given to all the folders

Comment: the permissions have been given to all the folders, still it is not working

Answer (score 1):

I normally suggest installing snowsql in `/opt/snowflake` - but the install in `/opt` should be good.

You'll need to ensure you've done the following in a multi-user linux host:

- changed the access permissions using the `chmod` command, I normally do `chmod 777 /opt/snowflake/snowsql`
- checked each user account's PATH environment variable to ensure `/opt` is in it, and edit their PATH as needed

When a user account invokes the snowsql client for the first time, it should create the `~/.snowsql` directory for them, but if you'd like to have it created for them, you can create a process to do that, just remember to run the `chown` command to the user.  Some shops do this and copy a company-specific config file to those new directories so users can use configs (`-c` argument in the command).

If all the above doesn't work, please post the actual error message the user accounts are receiving.  Right now we don't know what the actual error is:  is the command not being found (PATH issue) or is it a permissions issue (fixed by chmod), or is it something else?